# Does downloading objects from my google storage bucket result in charges?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have around 200GB of data in Google cloud storage, and have made it publicly available., Will it incur me bills if someone downloads the files/objects from my bucket?. My traffic is mostly from India, and my bucket location is US-East, Is that because of that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, of course. Per the [pricing tables](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing/#network-egress), GCS egress ranges from US$0.08/GiB to US$0.23/GiB. In addition, a download is a [class B operation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing/#operations-pricing), which are priced at US$0.004 per 10,000 operations (however, this usually amounts to a very small charge compared to the bandwidth, unless you are serving very large numbers of very small files).

Comment: thanks a lot.,Do I have to look at the egress charges or class B operation.?

Comment: @mutamilvativu - both. Study the pricing page for Cloud Storage.